# How to increment values that comes in add function inside jquery while selecting add button displays select box

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, function, onchange

I have put code to add select boxes continuously. I want to take values of each select boxes and display the result. the below code has on-change function of select_service_price that get the values of i statically but i want to increment the values of the on-change function of i should change each time when i click the add function that create additional select boxes.

```
$(document).on('click', '.add', function(){   var html = '';   var i =
0;   i += 1;    html += '
<tr>
   ';    html += '
   <td>
      <select
         name="item_unit[]" onchange = "select_service_price('+i+')"
         class="form-control item_unit">
         <option value="">Select
            Unit
         </option>
         <?php echo fill_unit_select_box($connect);
            ?>
      </select>
   </td>
   ';   //i += 1;    html += '
   <td><button type="button"
      name="remove" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove">
      <span
         class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></button>
   </td>
</tr>
';  
$('#item_table').append(html);  });
```

Comment: Put `var i = 0;` before in the global scope. Otherwise it will be reset every time the function is executed.

Comment: I have put var i = 0; and executed the above program but it remains the same.

Comment: If you moved `var i = 0;` outside (before `$(document).on('click', '.add',...` instead of inside the function), I don't see how `i` can not be incremented each time the callback is called. Edit the question to include your updated attempt as well (add it after the current code to keep the history). Let's just hope it won't take another two weeks before you answer this comment.